# c# program crashing while outside of visual studio but when in visual studio everything works perfect

Tags: c#, debugging

So what's happening is that a program I wrote works fine when building and running it from inside VS, but once I release it, or try to run the debug version outside of VS, it dies at a specific line of code.  It seems to be here...

```
HttpResponseMessage httpReply = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

The last command it logged before it crashed is

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
```

This is what request is

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
request.Content = new StringContent($"client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&code={authCode}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Works 100% when running from VS, but outside, fails right there.  has anyone seen this before or knows how to get this fixed?  Would really appreciate this.

I also have a debug log from windbg of where it crashes, but I'm new and self taught so it makes little to no sense to me.

https://paste.mod.gg/hrafanxablbx/0

I've spent a fair bit of time on this program and would hate for it to all be a waste.  Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Everything works fine while under VS, I don't know how to even start fixing this one.  I basically found out exactly where it was crashing by putting logging code everywhere and see where it stops.  I was hoping that would clue me in to what's going on.  unfortunately not.  I went through the answers that have already been posted on other similar questions but no luck.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]? What is the application type?

Comment: When you run it "outside of VS", are you actually running it on same machine? Is `http://localhost:3000` reachable from there?

Comment: Is there more than one project being started when you run it from VS?

Comment: What kind of application are you writing? E.g. a web service or a console app? If you're unsure then show us your `Program.cs` (at least the startup part) please.

Comment: Okay so while making the minimal example, I couldn't reproduce the error.  it worked just fine outside of VS, so just on a whim I tried to execute the code outside of the thread that I was putting it in and ... it works!  I don't understand it, but I"m super happy.  Thank you very much for taking a look at this post and for just suggesting the minimal example.  That set me on the path to getting this working.

Comment: To answer those questions, it's a WPF app, and yes it was the same machine.  For some reason changing the location of where the code was executed from made all the difference.  I still don't understand why it would work in VS and not outside but it's all working now.